# How to Round numbers at 0.6, 1,6, 2,6,...?

Tags: dart

I want this to be true for all numbers. I don't want to type this for all numbers of course.

```
 if (overs == 0.6) {
  overs = 1.0;
}
```

I want that if for example 1.6, is reached, it should be converted to 2. I want this to be true for all numbers.

Further Clarification: I don't want it to round at For eg 0.5, i want it to round at 0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insights porvided by @Amsakanna helped me solve the problem. I am posting the exact solution here:

```
 if ((overs - overs.floor()) > 0.55) 
{
overs = overs - (overs - overs.floor()) + 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### One Liner

```
double roundAt6(double n) => (n - n.floor()) > 0.5 ? n.ceil() : n;
```

### Detailed

```
void main() {
  final double overs = 5.6;
  print('result: ${roundAt6(overs)}');
}

double roundAt6(double n) {
  final double decimalPart = n - n.floor();
  print('decimal part: $decimalPart');
  final bool didExceed = decimalPart > 0.5;
  print('didExceed: $didExceed');
  return didExceed ? n.ceil() : n;
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks!
" if ((overs - overs.floor()) > 0.5) {
      overs = overs - (overs - overs.floor()) + 1;
    } "

Answer (score 0):

Use [round()](https://api.dartlang.org/be/162405/dart-core/num/round.html) method.

> Returns the integer closest to `this`.

### Example

```
overs = overs.round()
```

Comment: How exactly can i implement this to all numbers, please help

Comment: @AmanKataria Did you check the link? An example of implementation is provided there. It should be `overs = overs.round()`.

Comment: I don't want it to round at 0.5, in want it to round at 0.6

Comment: @AmanKataria I know what you're asking. I didn't make an answer. I just showed you how to implement this answer.

Comment: I want to know how. How can i symbolise all number in a funtion.

Comment: That apart. Why does you question say "Whats the symbol for numbers in dart?"? I'm just curious. Could you please give a better title and edit your question to avoid downvotes?

Comment: for eg: if ( overs == <int>.6) {
overs=overs+0.4}

I know this wouldnt work since <int> doesnt represent all integers. I just wrote this to let you know what i mean. 

What should replace <int> here

Comment: It is very easy to give an answer for this. It involves a custom function which can very well be written by you. Could you please try writing it and if you're stuck at some point then perhaps people at stack overflow can help you?

Comment: I am stuck here;
Its will be very easy if you can tell if you can tell me how to generalise

 if (overs == 0.6) {
  overs = 1.0;
}

If you know how to do this, Please tell me how can i represent all numbers, instead of just one number in this funtion.

Comment: You can generalize any number by subtracting the number from its `floor` counterpart.

Comment: `overs - overs.floor()` would give you the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ceil()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/num/ceil.html)

> Returns the least integer no smaller than this.

### Example

`overs = overs.ceil()`

Comment: `ceil` would return 2.0 even for 1.3. I don't know if the OP wants that.

Comment: @Amsakanna Can you help me out with this